# Apply user defined function on whole dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, apply, user-defined-functions

I have to perform the same data cleaning for multiple CSV files. I wrote a function to do it but I'm not getting any solution. I understand to use a user-defined function we must use the apply() function but those are for rows and columns and I want to do it for the whole dataframe.
My function code is below:

```
def transform_data(df):
   # split into multiple columns
   df = pd.concat([df['Unnamed: 0'], df['NFHS-5'].str.split(' ', expand=True),
                df['Unnamed: 2'], df['NFHS-4']], axis=1)
   # rename columns
   df = df.rename(columns={0: 'AP_NFHS_5_Urban', 2: 'AP_NFHS_5_Rural', 4: 'AP_NFHS_5_Total',
                        'Unnamed: 0': 'State_NFHS', 'NFHS-4': 'AP_NFHS_4'})
   # join 2 columns
   df['AP_NFHS_5_Total'] = df['AP_NFHS_5_Total'].fillna(df['Unnamed: 2'])
   # remove null columns
   df = df.dropna(subset=['AP_NFHS_5_Total'])
   df = df.dropna(subset=['AP_NFHS_5_Rural'])
   return df
```

How should I call it? Can I even do it?
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to call it on whole dataframe, you can use regular function call, like `transform_data(df)` where `transform_data` is your function you defined above and `df` is your data loaded from csv (`df = pd.read_csv(...)`).

Comment: @Nerxis, I tried doing that but I wasn't getting any result.

Comment: So this `df_transformed = transform_data(df)` does not work for you? If you need more help you need to post minimal reproducible example (data example, how you call the function, and so on). I guess you do not call it correctly but when I do not see how you try to call it it's hard to tell.

Comment: Thanks @Nerxis. It does work. I wasn't calling it correctly.